# Kivy - change on_release attribute to "changing screen" from Python code

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I got a problem that I could not find any way to bind "changing screen" to `on_release` attribute of a widget of my kivy file from Python. I want `on_release` attribute will change over time by some conditions. My code is very long so I will shorten it. If there is any part you want to see, I will add it.

```
class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass


class AVCard(Screen):
    pass


class UpdateVariables(Screen):
    currentpr = ObjectProperty(None)
    currentcardpr = ObjectProperty(None)
    minute_in_day = NumbericProperty()
    ...

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(UpdateVariables,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval((self.update_time), 1)
        self.now = datetime.now()

    def update_time(self, dt):
        self.timelablepr.text = '[size=20][b]' + time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

        self.hour = int(time.strftime("%H"))
        self.minute = int(time.strftime("%M"))
        self.minute_in_day = self.hour*60 + self.minute

        if self.minute_in_day in range (100, 200):
            self.currentpr.text = "this is AV"
            self.currentcardpr.on_release = self.switch_to(Screen(name='av')) #-> from here
        if self.minute_in_day in range (200, 300):
            self.currentpr.text = "..."
            self.currentcardpr.on_release = self.switch_to(Screen(name='...')) #-> another screen


class ScreenApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='home'))
        sm.add_widget(AVCard(name='av'))
        ...
        return sm
```

and this is my .kv file:

```
<HomeScreen>:
    name: 'home'
    ...

    UpdateVariables:
        currentpr: current
        currentcardpr: currentcard

    MDCard: #-> this is the card whose on_release attribute is changable
        id: currentcard
        on_release:
        ...
        MDLabel:
            id: current
            text: ''
            ...

    MDCard: #-> this is the card whose on_release attribute is unchangable, so at some special time, it will have the same destination
        ...
        on_release:
            root.manager.current = 'av'
            app.root.transition = FadeTransition(duration=0.1)



<AVScreen>:
    name: 'av'
    ...
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Trigger any function with on_release command. After that you just need to change one variable to check which page you are in. So you can now use self.manager.current = 'otherpagename' after if settlement.

Comment: @320V Im sorry sir, can you guide me more clearly what I should do? Thank you very much